# Fourier transform in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: fourier-analysis

I must implement Fourier transform in cylindrical co-ordinates.
Matlab offer fft function. How can I use this function ?

Comment: Are you working with a 3D transform, or are you dealing with a FT in planes that are symmetric about an axis (as in an optical system with rotational symmetry about an axis)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm working with 3D transform.

Comment: Isn't this just a Hankel transform? If so, there are fast Hankel transform functions available for Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, you can write

$$\hat{f}(v_{\rho},v_{\phi},v_z) = \int_0^{\infty} d \rho \rho \int_0^{2 \pi} d \phi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \: f(\rho, \phi,z) \exp[-i 2 \pi v_{\rho} \rho \cos{(v_{\phi} - \phi)}] \exp{(-i 2 \pi v_z z)}  $$

First, perform a F.T. (i.e., matlab fft) in the $z$ variable.  Now you can express the result in a Fourier series in $v_{\phi}$ and use a Bessel transform over $v_{\rho}$.

Comment: Can you give me an example to verify the code?

Comment: You might write $\bar{f}(\rho, \phi,v_z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \: f(\rho, \phi,z) \exp{(-i 2 \pi v_z z)}$.  You can do this using the Matlab fft function.  Now you are left, for each $v_z$, to do a polar FFT over $(\rho, \phi)$.  Scroll to the bottom of this page: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~elad/software/ and you will get Matlab code for a polar FFT, and a paper that describes how it is done.

Comment: What is connection between $\widehat{f}(vρ,vϕ,vz)$ and $ \overline{f}(ρ,ϕ,vz)$?

Comment: They are Fourier transforms over the $z$ coordinate.

Comment: Thanks for information. I read again and I understood your response. The basic algorithm is: -transform Cartesian coordinates in cylindrical coordinates. In Matlab exist the function car2pol.For X,Y, Z vectors which represent Cartesian coordinates,it's necessary to obtain the cylindrical coordinates  (ρ,ϕ,$v_z$). So we write:[ρ,ϕ,$v_z$]=car2pol(X,Y,Z).F is the vector with all values of f(ρ,ϕ,$v_z$). I apply fft to F: G=fft(f); Let be Polar_FFT polar fft function, where we suppose that is implemented. For having the final result I must write:    $H=\text{Polar_FFT}(G*exp[−i2πv_ρρcos(v_ϕ−ϕ)])$?

Comment: $*$ is scalar product

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I have one question
I must implement Fourier transform in cylindrical co-ordinates for a simple sinus.
How can i express this function in r, theta and z?

Comment: @Toader: This is not an answer. If you have a separate question, please use the [Ask Question link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) near the upper right of the page. I am converting your answer to a comment on Ron Gordon's answer in case he can help you.

Comment: @Toader: I'd like to help you, but I have no idea what you mean by a sinus.  I think you mean a sine function, but this is too vague for me to answer.  Please open a new question and provide some detail.

Comment: @Ron Gordon, Can you please show how to write the Fourier transform in cylindrical coordinates?